# How to get the value of root element (without .Net 4)

Tags: c#, xml

How can we read the attribute value of root element of xml? I am using the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NPGSJ//DTD full length article DTD version  
[
<!ENTITY xobx1 SYSTEM "abcx1.pdf" NDATA pdf>
]
<article id="abc" type="a">
<fm>
</fm>
<article>
```

I need to read this xml file and want to store the attribute value of article tag in some string to check the category of an article .

Please guide

Comment: Using [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb387098.aspx) is one nice way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument(); 
    xdoc.Load(@"C:\Temp\emi20154a.xml"); 
    string root_attribure1 = xdoc.DocumentElement.Attributes[0].Value;
    string root_attribure2 = xdoc.DocumentElement.Attributes[1].Value; 

    Console.WriteLine("root_attribure1" + root_attribure1); 
    Console.WriteLine("root_attribure2" + root_attribure2); 

    Console.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Something like this :

```
//You can replace "C:" with your specified path
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\yourxmlfilename.xml");
var root_attribure1 = xdoc.Root.Attribute("id").Value;
var root_attribure2 = xdoc.Root.Attribute("type").Value;
```

Comment: x document class is available in .net framework 4 , i need to write in 2003.

Answer (score 1):

It works.

```
        var x = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"+    
                "<article id=\"abc\" type=\"a\">"+
                    "<fm>"+
                    "</fm>"+
                "</article>";

        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(x);
        var id = doc.SelectSingleNode("/article/@id").Value;
        var type = doc.SelectSingleNode("/article/@type").Value;
```

Comment: hi @S Stadler, i can't give hardcode because the value of id and type is depend on the xml. i need code which load the xml document and check the value of type and id which can be different based on xml supplied by clients

Comment: Hi pooja, For sure, I just put it to give a sequence to the code.